# "Cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a question that has been answer multiple times, but none seem to fit my problem

Just trying to set the text of a label when the view loads when I get the error

```
import UIKit

class ProblemsViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var respiratoryText: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    respiratoryText.text("e  ")
   }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
respiratoryText.text("e  ")
```

The correct syntax is

```
respiratoryText.text = "e  "
```

Calling text with parentheses and a string inside of the parentheses is like invoking a function called `text` that takes a parameter of type `String`. Such a function does not exist on `UILabel`.

Text is a mutable property, not a function, so you can just assign `String` values to it without any function calls.